# Multiple roles in Spring Security

Tags: xml, spring-security

I'm doing a project with Spring security, I give roles to my user depending in the department and position, for example `Admin` and `HR`, how can I make that only if have 2 roles can enter `access="'admin' and 'hr'"` not `access="'admin'or 'hr'"`?

Comment: Please post some details about where you would like to do this check. On the page, controller, XML file, etc. What have you tried already that hasn't worked? Posting more information in your question will help others figure out how to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options first use SPeL like bellow

```
access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_HR')"
```

and second option is,make a custom rol say ROLE_ADMINnHR and then do normal

```
access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMINnHR')"
```

NOTE:For better clarity, you need to explain your question a bit more.